# How To Integrate Bitbucket With Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket

As near as I can tell I can't find any plugins that do the job.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Use the command line.

Comment: ...as in streamlined 1 click solutions I can do right in Visual Studio Code?